# How to run methods before and after Lombok @Setter

Tags: java, lombok

I want some of my methods to run before and after the Lombok @Setter.
For example:

```
@Setter(after="save")
private String name;
```

This should run method called "save" after the original setter has assigned a value to the field.
So after compilation it should look like this:

```
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.save();
}
```

Maybe there is something I could do with "onMethod" parameter? Sorry, I'm not professional in annotations.

Comment: Even if this was possible, which I _think_ it isn't based on [the docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter), it would _definitely_ be a bad practice. A setter should set a field, any additional side-effects are unexpected and hard-to-understand by other developers. TooMuchMagicException. Just name your method `setNameAndSave()` and write it yourself if you really, really want to do this. The common way is to set all the fields, then call `repository.save(object)`.

Comment: @PetrJaneček The problem is that I have to have this 'save' method for every single field. If I have like 30 fields in the class it is very cumbersome and annoying to create 30 setters. This 'save' method just saves an updated field to the file, so it shouldn't be hard-to-understand by other developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently indeed no way to do this; `onMethod` isn't going to help either (SOURCE/DISCLAIMER: I'm a core lombok dev).

We do have some plans to add such a thing, but before you go ahead and write a PullRequest to add such a feature, discuss it first. There are various ways to go here. The primary issue is syntax.

You can't put java code in an annotation (you can put it in a string but we veto such a move; your IDE is not going to help you, it's got the wrong syntax highlighting, and so on). You can't, unfortunately, put a method reference in an annotation either. You could put a string in there that mentions a method but we don't like that either (again, wrong colouring, no IDE autocomplete support).

That leaves magic naming (you make a method called `afterName`), but at that point lombok saves you nearly nothing, so why not just write the setter. A second option is to have a single 'validate' method that is called after *any* setter and is e.g. marked by an annotation. That's more the direction we're leaning into.

There's more to consider: Sometimes you'd want to mutate the incoming value before assigning it, and the same mutation should be done in case you have a builder, or have a constructor that accepts this param, as well. Thus, we have:

- Post-set actions after any setter *and* construction, such as `save()`.
- Pre-"setting", validate and/or mutate, after any setter *and* construction. For example, let's say you have a `setAge()` method and you want to throw an exception if someone attempts to pass a negative value. The set shouldn't even happen, so a post-set handler can't do the job (it'd be too late, the object is already in an invalid state and you'd want to avoid this). Complication: Given that we want to do this pre-setting the field, how does this method get the values, then?

Hopefully that illustrates why this feature isn't (yet) in lombok and why it's a matter of a simple PR to add it.